# Java script: Load sub json message through $ref attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this Json schema :

```
{
  "name":"Myname", 
   "Job":"Myjob", 
   "item":{
      "$ref": "#/definitions/address"
    },
    "definitions":
    {
        "address":
        {
            "street":"My street",
            "postalCode":"11111"
        }
     }
}
```

What I want to know if there's a way in JS to access directly to address attribute content and read it through its reference #/definitions/address which exists in "item" attribute.
So I will get as Json object in the result:

```
        "address":
        {
            "street":"My street",
            "postalCode":"11111"
        }
```

Comment: By `#/definitions/address`, you mean a URL pattern ? Like routing ?

Comment: I thought of something like URL routing. You should do `$ref`, replace `/` with `.` and then access the `address` data. Make sure to skip `#` too

Comment: I have just updated the question.
What I need is a java script solution.

Comment: see my answer, is that what you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to access the address object from the definitions index, which is referred at your address index, I think you could use this way

**[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/robinat130/pwto3cmp/)**

```
var object = {
  "name":"Myname", 
   "Job":"Myjob", 
   "address":{
      "$ref": "#/definitions/address"
    },
    "definitions":
    {
        "address":
        {
            "street":"My street",
            "postalCode":"11111"
        }
     }
};

var add_ref = object.address.$ref.split('/');

console.log(object[add_ref[1]][add_ref[2]]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the Json schema that I gave you is just an example. I would something more general. The path may be presented in 3 or 4 "sub path" it can be for example #/path1/path2/path3 or #/path1 or  #/path1/path2/path3/path4 or any other way. I think that there's a way to access directly to the reference with js otherwise I will develop a js function that do it.